# Removing or Switching Events on Highcharts

Tags: angular, events, highcharts

If zooming on the  'x'- or 'y'-axis is enabled for the chart I want set different selection-Events. The problem is, that I can't remove Events, only add more events to the chart.

**Example**: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-csyvrn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) Line: 62-66 and 73, 77

The reason why I want to do this is, because if the zoomtype is changed from x to y and I select a area (in the chart) there is no x.min or x.max value and the program stops running correctly.

**Edit:**
[Stackblitz new](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpexuj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I've updated the example to represent what I am want to do. I initialize the chart with the method that the program prints out the min- and max values on the xAxis. If I toggle to Y-Axis-Zooming I want to print the min and max values of the y-Axis. And the problem is that he doesn't remove the "Selection-Event" of the chart.

Comment: Did you give https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#removeEvent a read? This removes all 'selection' events: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpexuj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @ewolden yes i did and this doesn't work

Comment: In what way does it not work? It removes the event for me

Comment: At the first. If I use Highcharts.removeEvent() it displays an compile error: "Property 'removeEvent' does not exist on type 'Static'." At the second if I call the removeEvent-Method it doesn't remove the methods from the ChartObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it works in these [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c68czc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). I don't know why I had trouble or doesn't work in my project. I think it's important to update the zoomtype after removing the event of the chart:

```
  Highcharts.removeEvent(this.chart, 'selection');
  this.chart.update({ chart: { zoomType: 'y' } });
```

**Short**: Use `Highcharts.removeEvent();`

If you get trouble with the problem: `property is not defined on "Static"` simply add to the '@types/highcharts/index.d.ts' the following code:

```
     /**
     * Removes an event that was added with Highcharts#addEvent
     * 
     * @see {@link https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#removeEvent}
     * 
     * @param element The element to remove events on.
     * @param type The type of events to remove. If undefined, all events are removed from the element.
     * @param cb The specific callback to remove. If undefined, all events that match the element and optionally the type are removed.
     */
     removeEvent(element: HTMLElement | ElementObject | object,
         type?: string,
         cb?: (evt: Event) => void): void;
```